# insert into sqlite table with unique column

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm inserting values into my table (from python code) as follows:

```
cur.execute("insert into t(a, b, c) values (?, ?, ?)", (a, b, c))
```

There is a `unique constraint` on column c. What is a common way of `insert` if I want to cover the case when we're inserting duplicate value for c column?
I have some ideas

1. select everything from t to list and test before inserting if the value is already present
2. try-catch block
3. some more sophisticated sqlite statement

How would you test it?

thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use [INSERT OR REPLACE](https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) to update rows with a unique constraint,
or [INSERT OR IGNORE](https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) to ignore inserts which conflict with a unique constraint:

```
import sqlite3

def insert_or_replace():
    # https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html
    connection=sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
    cursor=connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE foo (bar INTEGER UNIQUE, baz INTEGER)')
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO foo (bar,baz) VALUES (?, ?)',(1,2))
    cursor.execute('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO foo (bar,baz) VALUES (?, ?)',(1,3))
    cursor.execute('SELECT * from foo')
    data=cursor.fetchall()
    print(data)
    # [(1, 3)]


def on_conflict():
    # https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html
    connection=sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
    cursor=connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE foo (bar INTEGER UNIQUE, baz INTEGER)')
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO foo (bar,baz) VALUES (?, ?)',(1,2))
    cursor.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO foo (bar,baz) VALUES (?, ?)',(1,3))
    cursor.execute('SELECT * from foo')
    data=cursor.fetchall()
    print(data)
    # [(1, 2)]    

insert_or_replace()
on_conflict()
```

These sqlite commands are probably faster than writing Python code to do the same thing, though to test this you could use Python's `timeit` module to test the speed of various implementations. For example, you could run

```
python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.insert_or_replace()'
```

versus

```
python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.filter_nonunique_rows_in_Python()'
```

versus

```
python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.insert_with_try_catch_blocks()'
```

Comment: Thank you. Is this more efficient than testing in python as point 1? For my situation `insert or ignore` is ideal.

Comment: @xralf: sqlite is written in C, so allowing sqlite to perform the filtering is most likely faster than writing your own code to do the same thing in Python. (Even if the Python code were as fast as the C code, you'd still have to load the entire table into a Python object...) Since you asked how to test this claim, however, I suggested using `python -mtimeit ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Depends :)

If there is only one inserter the 1 might be the most efficient.

If there are several inserters you have to use 2 as under 1 you could test and seem OK but another inserter adds the C value you have so it fails

Comment: Thank you, it seems there will be only one inserter (so far, can change in the future). I have it implemented as 1, but it's (this test) quite a lot typing if I want to write new inserting code and I'm not sure if it's efficient to test e.g. 10000 values in the list. Maybe sqlite has something more sophisticated with defining indeces.